# How to create an alert message in Google app script while deploying a web app?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, msgbox

I am trying to create a web app using Google app script, that if you press a button, you may get an alert message.

In the home.gs file I tried this :

```
function let_user_decide()
{
Browser.msgBox('Greetings', 'Press Yes or No?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
};
```

unfortunately I keep getting this when I press the button when I should get the alert message :

> Exception: Cannot call Browser.inputBox() from this context.

Important to mention : my script is using Google spreadsheet but the msgBox should appear in the webapp! In addition, I use HTML

Any idea what am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browser.msgBox is indeed only available in the spreadsheet interface, not in webapps.

You have a lot of alternatives to throw alerts but you should mention wether you use UiApp or HTML Service.

In UiApp you can create a [popupPanel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/popup-panel) for example while in HTML you can throw alerts (throw new Error('sample alert'))  or use JQuery Ui elements to do that.

Comment: Edited. using html, can you explain more please?

Comment: Actually, I have tried to replace this line with - 'alert', 'window.alert' same for 'confirm' and 'prompt'. and it haven't work for me still.

Comment: In addition, i couldn't find a way to make a Yes_No alert in the way you offer (throw new error)

Comment: Please explain how to use the html service for alerts